# Does adding a constant expression to the SELECT list affect the query execution time in DB2?

Tags: sql, database, db2

```
SELECT
  id,
  'great' performance
FROM employee;
```

As this query have a run time column, will this affect the query processing time.

Comment: Yes, but more or less unmeasurable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes because there is additional effort to create that extra column for each returned row. Is it big? No.

The query compiler/optimizer need to carry some extra metadata and during query execution time that extra field for each returned row needs to be created and populated with that constant. But there is no search (in-memory or disk) involved.